# Apollo graphql interface typedef

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I Have apollo interface link this:

```
interface PageLayout {
        _id: String!
        id: ID! @globalID
        title: String
        subtitle: String
        template: String! @default(value:"none")
        layout: String
        layoutMobile: String
        showCount: Float
        showCountMobile: Float
        imageHeight: Int
        cardDesign: String
        cardShadow: Int
    }
```

and have this type that implements the interface:

```
type PageLayoutBannerRow implements PageLayout {
        _id: String!
        id: ID! @globalID
        title: String
        subtitle: String
        template: String! @default(value:"none")
        layout: String
        layoutMobile: String
        showCount: Float
        showCountMobile: Float
        imageHeight: Int
        cardDesign: String
        cardShadow: Int

        banners: [PageLayoutBanner]! @default(value:[])
    }
```

for each type I have to copy all Interface properties to my type.

Is there any solution to write my types like this?

```
type PageLayoutBannerRow implements PageLayout {
        # not copy interface attributes

        banners: [PageLayoutBanner]! @default(value:[])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way around it. See the docs for more details https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces

Depending on what you want to achieve you may want to take a look at unions https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types (but from your example it looks like you should use an interface for sure).